# Using data binding to set textedit property

Tags: java, android, layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I'm trying to manipulate with my TextEdit to display drawable.

custom_edit.xml:

`<variable name="var" type="com.example.xxx.app.CustomEditText"/>` and `android:drawableLeft="@{var.customButton}"`

My CustomEditText extends RelativeLayout: `public class ScannerEditText extends RelativeLayout`.

```
...
public Drawable customButton
...

private void init(Context context){
   CustomEditBinding customEditBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView((Activity) getContext(), R.layout.custom_edit);
   customButton = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.on_name);
   ...
   }
```

When I'm trying to call customEditBinding.setVar it wants to take CustomEditText as a parameter.
I'm new to android and after following the official documentation I could not find solution.

Comment: If you would simply like the drawable to be the drawable sourced from `R.drawable.on_name`, you may set it directly in the XML file as `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/on_name"`

Comment: I know but I need to do it this way.